# Concat files in one directory based on their extension

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, concatenation

I have a directory which holds multiple big size files of different extensions:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
text_file.txt
text_file2.txt
json_file.json
json_file2.json
...
```

My goal is to join all files into three groups based on their extension. The script wouldnt need to join everything in one run, I can change the extension and run the script 3 times. The main goal would be to join all certain type ( let's say .csv ) files in one category. I've found this script in stackoverflow but it throws me errors:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("/Users/user/Desktop")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f'*.{extension}')]
#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The code throws me this error:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 543, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Other side of question would be in terms of memory efficiency, when should I start concatenating files line by line rather than the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This script will concatenate files that pandas can read into a DataFrame, preserving the header. All your columns need to be in the same order for this to work.

```py
# cat_header.py
import sys
import pandas as pd

header = True
for file in sys.argv[2:]:
    pd.read_csv(file).to_csv(sys.argv[1], header=header, index=False, mode="a")
    header = False
```

It runs as:

```sh
python3 cat_header.py output.csv *.csv
```

---

For `.txt` files:

```py
# cat_files.py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as out_fh:
    for file in sys.argv[2:]:
        with open(file, "r") as in_fh:
            out_fh.write("".join(in_fh.readlines()))
```

It runs as:

```sh
python3 cat_files.py output.txt *.txt
```